# Disable new DAGs by default

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

Is there a setting in Cloud Composer / Airflow that can disable new DAGs in the DAGs folder by default, without the need for specifying this in the DAG files themsleves?

I want to be able to load these DAGs in to a development environment where users should just run these DAGs manually rather than them being scheduled.

I had a look here, https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg
but I couldn't find anything obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Yes there is one.
- It's called [`dags_are_paused_at_creation`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg#L122)

Comment: Nice, I didn't realise 'Off' was what is called Paused. Thanks